# What is the purpose of the \btypeout control sequence?

Tags: package-writing

I've checked the index from The LaTeX Companion 2nd Edition, and the LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual and neither have any reference to the `\btypeout{}` control sequence.

I've seen it in the context of defining and redefining commands, but I'm unable to glean its purpose.

I would appreciate a summary of the sequence's purpose, and please link to a textual reference that defines it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only mentions of `\btypeout` that I could find on the web are contained in various files called `Thesis.cls` which start with

```
%%
%% This is file `Thesis.cls', based on 'ECSthesis.cls', by Steve R. Gunn
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% Created by Steve R. Gunn, modified by Sunil Patel: www.sunilpatel.co.uk
```

One such file is at https://github.com/andrewbolster/thesis/blob/master/Thesis.cls. (The - I believe - original source of that file https://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/ now serves a different file called `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`, which does not mention `\btypeout`.)

There `\btypeout` is defined as

```
\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
```

and `\bhrule` as

```
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}
```

which means that the command basically sends a lot of dashes to the `.log` file and console output, then its argument and then another row of dashes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}

\begin{document}
Lorem

\btypeout{Hullo}
\end{document}
```

shows

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hullo
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in the `.log`.

---

Personally, I don't think this command is particularly useful. If you want to write a package, it may be more useful to use the standard LaTeX commands `\PackageError`, `\PackageWarning`, `\PackageWarningNoLine` or `\PackageInfo` to send errors, warnings of infos to the `.log` file/terminal output. Then the messages use a standardised format that can be picked up by `.log` file parsers.

---

`Thesis.cls` is also not something I would use. The version linked above is basically 500 lines of (possibly outdated) code no one maintains any more.